# PLSQL recursive query for friend analysis

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, recursive-query

I have a socialnetwork table. Name of the table is RELATION_TABLE.
I have three columns. userid_1, userid_2, relationtypecode (like closefriend, family member, acquaintance, college friend etc)

Table structure and sample records:

```
DROP table RELATION_TABLE;
create table RELATION_TABLE
(
    USER_ID_1 NUMBER,
    USER_ID_2 NUMBER,
    RELATION_TYPE_CODE VARCHAR2(100) 
);

INSERT INTO RELATION_TABLE(USER_ID_1,USER_ID_2,RELATION_TYPE_CODE) 
VALUES(1,2,'CLOSE FRIEND');
INSERT INTO RELATION_TABLE(USER_ID_1,USER_ID_2,RELATION_TYPE_CODE) 
VALUES(4,1,'HIGH SCHOOL FRIEND');
INSERT INTO RELATION_TABLE(USER_ID_1,USER_ID_2,RELATION_TYPE_CODE) 
VALUES(5,2,'FAMILY MEMBER');
INSERT INTO RELATION_TABLE(USER_ID_1,USER_ID_2,RELATION_TYPE_CODE) 
VALUES(1,6,'COLLEAGUE');
INSERT INTO RELATION_TABLE(USER_ID_1,USER_ID_2,RELATION_TYPE_CODE) 
VALUES(3,4,'PARTNER');
INSERT INTO RELATION_TABLE(USER_ID_1,USER_ID_2,RELATION_TYPE_CODE) 
VALUES(3,6,'COLLEAGUE');
COMMIT;
```

Sample records:

```
USER_ID_1    USER_ID_2    RELATION_TYPE_CODE
1              2           CLOSE FRIEND
4              1           HIGH SCHOOL FRIEND
5              2           FAMILY MEMBER
1              6           COLLEAGUE
3              4           WIFE
3              6           COLLEAGUE
```

According to sample records:user:
1 has a relation with 4 and 4 has a relation with 3 and finally 4 has a relation with 6 so 1 may have a relation with 4,3 and 6.

So I need to write a recursive query in order to insert all possible relations.
I tried to use connect by prior however there is no direct relation like child-parent relationship. Any userid can exist in USER_ID_1 column or USER_ID_2 column. There may be loops, I also need to ignore these loops.

Do you have any method suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?  In particular, 12C has improved syntax for these types of queries.

Comment: I am using 11g :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your dataset doesn't have a directionality to the relationships, if you want to get all transitive relationships, you'll need to handle relationship chains that start with either `USIR_ID_1` -> `USER_ID_2` or `USER_ID_2` -> `USER_ID_1`.

As you mentioned you are on 11g, recursive subfactoring might be an option for you, but since that didn't hit until 11gR2, I'll avoid that in this example and use `CONNECT BY`.

In your example, you expect overall to get relationship records for `user # 1` to `users # 3,4,6`. (And presumably user # 2, from the `CLOSE FRIEND`     relationsnhip you included)
To assemble these relationships, one might try to first start with a combined query for a `USER_ID_1`-rooted relationship tree, plus a`USER_ID_2`-rooted relationship tree with `NOCYCLE` to ignore loops(but this won't work):

```
SELECT
  CONNECT_BY_ROOT USER_ID_2 AS STARTING_USER_ID,
  USER_ID_1                 AS RELATED_USER_ID
FROM RELATION_TABLE
START WITH USER_ID_2 = 1
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR USER_ID_1 = USER_ID_2
UNION
SELECT
  CONNECT_BY_ROOT USER_ID_1 AS STARTING_USER_ID,
  USER_ID_2                 AS RELATED_USER_ID
FROM RELATION_TABLE
START WITH USER_ID_1 = 1
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR USER_ID_2 = USER_ID_1
ORDER BY 1 ASC, 2 ASC;
```

Result:

```
STARTING_USER_ID  RELATED_USER_ID  
1                 2                
1                 3                
1                 4                
1                 6
```

This seems close (it has the three relationships you mentioned, plus the `1 -> 2` relationship where `user # 1` is on the `USER_ID_1` side)

But looking more closely at the data, there are missing relationships.  If you look at the records, `user # 2` is connected to `user # 5`, and `user # 1` is connected to `user # 2`, so `user # 1` should also be connected to `user # 5`.  I believe you pointed this out in your post--that there is no direct parent-child relationship (there's no directionality to the network, but there is directionality to the queries)

To get at this, one (inefficient) way is to query against the combined set of `a -> b` and `b -> a` relationships--to double the data set so the hierarchical query can proceed as though relationships were directional.

In the below query, `user # 1` can now navigate through `user # 2` to connect to `user # 5`.  One side effect of this query is that it creates artificial self-relationships that must be removed.  In the provided example, a `UNION ALL` is present to add-back genuine self-relationships.

For the sake of space, I'll use `LISTAGG` here, to compress the results.

```
WITH PSEUDO_DIRECTED_RELATION AS (
  SELECT
    USER_ID_1 AS LEFT_ID,
    USER_ID_2 AS RIGHT_ID
  FROM RELATION_TABLE
  UNION
  SELECT
    USER_ID_2 AS LEFT_ID,
    USER_ID_1 AS RIGHT_ID
  FROM RELATION_TABLE)
SELECT STARTING_ID, LISTAGG(RELATED_ID,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY RELATED_ID ASC) AS RELATED_USERS
FROM (
SELECT
  DISTINCT
  CONNECT_BY_ROOT RIGHT_ID AS STARTING_ID,
  LEFT_ID                  AS RELATED_ID
FROM PSEUDO_DIRECTED_RELATION
WHERE LEFT_ID <> CONNECT_BY_ROOT RIGHT_ID
START WITH RIGHT_ID = 1
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR LEFT_ID = RIGHT_ID
UNION ALL
SELECT
  USER_ID_1 AS STARTING_ID,
  USER_ID_2 AS RELATED_ID
FROM RELATION_TABLE
WHERE USER_ID_1 = USER_ID_2
      AND USER_ID_1 = 1)
  GROUP BY STARTING_ID
ORDER BY 1 ASC;
```

Result:

```
STARTING_ID  RELATED_USERS  
1            2,3,4,5,6
```

Now `user # 1` is connected to `user # 5` through `user # 2`.
But maybe this is just linking everything to everything, so let's add a little more data:

```
INSERT INTO RELATION_TABLE VALUES (7,9,'Siblings');
INSERT INTO RELATION_TABLE VALUES (7,13,'Pen Pals');
INSERT INTO RELATION_TABLE VALUES (22,7,'Colleagues');
```

And rerun the query above.  `user # 1` should not be related (at all) to `user # 7`.

```
STARTING_ID  RELATED_USERS  
1            2,3,4,5,6
```

Now if we relate user # 7 to itself

```
INSERT INTO RELATION_TABLE VALUES (7,7,'Self');
```

And re-run targeting `user # 7` instead of `user # 1` (changing the `START WITH`, etc):

```
STARTING_ID  RELATED_USERS  
7            7,9,13,22
```

If you don't want to query for a single root user, you can drop the `START WITH` and self-relation predicate.

```
WITH PSEUDO_DIRECTED_RELATION AS (
  SELECT
    USER_ID_1 AS LEFT_ID,
    USER_ID_2 AS RIGHT_ID
  FROM RELATION_TABLE
  UNION
  SELECT
    USER_ID_2 AS LEFT_ID,
    USER_ID_1 AS RIGHT_ID
  FROM RELATION_TABLE)
SELECT STARTING_ID, LISTAGG(RELATED_ID,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY RELATED_ID ASC) AS RELATED_USERS
  FROM (
SELECT
  DISTINCT
  CONNECT_BY_ROOT RIGHT_ID AS STARTING_ID,
  LEFT_ID                  AS RELATED_ID
FROM PSEUDO_DIRECTED_RELATION
WHERE LEFT_ID <> CONNECT_BY_ROOT RIGHT_ID
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR LEFT_ID = RIGHT_ID
UNION ALL
SELECT
  USER_ID_1 AS STARTING_ID,
  USER_ID_2 AS RELATED_ID
FROM RELATION_TABLE
WHERE USER_ID_1 = USER_ID_2)
  GROUP BY STARTING_ID
ORDER BY 1 ASC, 2 ASC;
```

Result showing all transitively related users for each user:

```
STARTING_ID  RELATED_USERS  
1            2,3,4,5,6      
2            1,3,4,5,6      
3            1,2,4,5,6      
4            1,2,3,5,6      
5            1,2,3,4,6      
6            1,2,3,4,5      
7            7,9,13,22      
9            7,13,22        
13           7,9,22         
22           7,9,13
```

Comment: Thank you much for your answer

Answer (score 1):

With version.

```
WITH m AS
          (SELECT USER_ID_1 u1, USER_ID_2 u2 FROM RELATION_TABLE
           UNION
           SELECT USER_ID_2, USER_ID_1 FROM RELATION_TABLE),
     recur (usr, fri) AS
          (SELECT u1, u1 FROM m
           UNION ALL
           SELECT r.usr, u2 FROM recur r, m WHERE r.fri = m.u1)
           CYCLE fri SET cycle TO 1 DEFAULT 0
SELECT    usr,
         listagg(fri, ',') within GROUP (ORDER BY fri) friends
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT usr, fri FROM recur WHERE usr != fri AND cycle = 0)
GROUP BY  usr;
```

Comment: Thank you much for your help :)